# Can't read local json file : open failed:ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, json

I'm developping and android application in which i wan't to read a local json file to populate a ListView, the problem is that i can't read the local json file, and here how i proceed.

First i created an object class because i want to work with **ObjectMapper**.

already created the base classes (Theme, CouchesTheme and ClassesEvenement).

here's the subclasse **LireTheme**:

```
package com.myapp.theme;

public class LireTheme {

private Theme theme;
private CouchesTheme couchesTheme;
private ClassesEvenement classesEvenement;

private String message;
private boolean ok;

public LireTheme() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public LireTheme(Theme theme, CouchesTheme couchesTheme,
        ClassesEvenement classesEvenement, String message, boolean ok) {
    super();
    this.theme = theme;
    this.couchesTheme = couchesTheme;
    this.classesEvenement = classesEvenement;
    this.message = message;
    this.ok = ok;
}
public Theme getTheme() {
    return theme;
}
public void setTheme(Theme theme) {
    this.theme = theme;
}
public CouchesTheme getCouchesTheme() {
    return couchesTheme;
}
public void setCouchesTheme(CouchesTheme couchesTheme) {
    this.couchesTheme = couchesTheme;
}
public ClassesEvenement getClassesEvenement() {
    return classesEvenement;
}
public void setClassesEvenement(ClassesEvenement classesEvenement) {
    this.classesEvenement = classesEvenement;
}
public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}
public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
public boolean isOk() {
    return ok;
}
public void setOk(boolean ok) {
    this.ok = ok;
}

}
```

second i created a correspondence HashMap class of Theme list.

```
package com.myapp.recensement;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import com.myapp.theme.LireTheme;

public class LireThemes extends HashMap<String, ArrayList<LireTheme>> {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

and then use it like this.

```
package com.myapp.recensement;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

import com.myapp.theme.LireTheme;

public class LireThemesController {
private ObjectMapper objectMapper = null;
private JsonFactory jsonFactory = null;
private JsonParser jp = null;
private ArrayList<LireTheme> themeList = null;
private LireThemes lirethemes = null;
private File jsonFile;

boolean availble=false;

public LireThemesController() {
    objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();
}

public void init() {
    availble=isExternalStorageReadble();
    if(availble){
        Log.w("myApp", "file available");
    }else{
        Log.w("myApp", "file not available");
    }

    jsonFile = new File("c:\\lireThemes.json");
    try{
        jp = jsonFactory.createJsonParser(jsonFile);
        lirethemes = objectMapper.readValue(jp, LireThemes.class);
        themeList = lirethemes.get("themes");
    } catch(JsonParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public ArrayList<LireTheme> findAll() {
    return themeList;
}
public LireTheme findById(int id) {
    return themeList.get(id);
}

public boolean isExternalStorageReadble() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

and also already added the permission in the AndroidManifest.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

when i run i get this error :

```
12-29 04:16:04.287: W/System.err(2060): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /c:\lireThemes.json: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory).
```

any solution for that problem please ?

Comment: c: is the letter of your hard drive on windows isn't it ? it has nothing to do on android, especially if you're reading the external storage. Your file name has to be prefixed by the external storage dir path. Which can be found using some `Context.getExternalFilesDir()` method

Comment: I tried getAssets() and it works thank you for your anwser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot read a file on your Android device from c:\, which is a Windows File System path.

You have to copy your JSON file inside the Assets folder and then load it using

```
public String loadJSONFromAsset() {

String json = null;
try {

    InputStream is = getAssets().open("yourfilename.json");

    int size = is.available();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

    is.read(buffer);

    is.close();

    json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");


} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
return json;

}
```

Comment: thank you for the anwser, but should i create a context for getAssets()? no ?

Comment: Yes, you have to pass a context to your LireThemesController, then call context.getAssets().open(...);

Comment: that's it, tank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is `jsonFile = new File("c:\\lireThemes.json");`
There is no c:\lireThemes.json file on your android device.

If you add the file to your assets directory (in your project) you can access by `getAssets().open("lireThemes.json")` which will return an input stream
or you can put it in your res/raw folder and access it by `getActivity().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.lireThemes)` which will also return an input stream